# ListView under semi-transparent view. How to keep it scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

In some cases whole view  of  my fragment should be  covered with semi-trasparent overlay. But the ListView under this overlay should rest scrollable. Now it's scrolling very bad. How  to  keep it  scrollable underneath the semi-trasparent view?
Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/green">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/fade_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/semi_trasparent_white"
   />
```

Comment: what do you mean by "scrolling very bad"?

Comment: I mean scrooling not  smoothly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fade_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@color/orange" />

</RelativeLayout>
```